# How to make windows service keep running even when user logs out

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created a windows service using c# and deployed it in some machine. It's working well and good as long as the user is logged in. When user logs out, the service stop.

How can I make the windows service keep running irrespective of whether user is logged in or not? I want the service to run always until I go and stop it by myself.

User logs in as remote user to the machine (where the service is hosted) and can start or stop the service using an UI app. When he logs out, service stops.

Comment: by definition a windows service is independant of user logging in or not.. what makes it stop

Comment: Does the logged user have administrative privileges?

Comment: That's what they do, by default. So the answer is "take out whatever you've added that makes it dependent on a user session", but we can't tell you what that thing might be. Unless, of course, you're using "windows service" to mean something other than an actual windows service, but instead e.g. a console application.